# How can I display Translucent Image over Other Layout in Android?

Tags: android, imageview

How can i Convert it to translucent ImageView?

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/frag_preview_iv_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

 </ImageView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the alpha property of the ImageView.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/frag_preview_iv_preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:alpha="0.5">
</ImageView>
```

This property goes from `0 to 1` so the values could be `0.1`, `0.25`, `0.3` and so on until `1`.

If you want so set this property from code, you can use the `.setImageAlpha()` method. I let there the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#setImageAlpha(int)

Just as information, from RGB we have 3 channels and alpha is the fourth channel that define the opacity.

Comment: its working , but not over other layout ... i should have elevation too.

Comment: Didn't know where you would use it, but yes, just add elevation. If my answer solve your problem, please, consider picking it as the correct answer!